# VBA to Batch Update Folder of MS Word Files with Excel Links

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've got a folder full of MS word docs, all with the same header, containing a couple of fields linked to an excel file to control the project phase and issue date in one spot.

I'm trying to figure out a way to use VBA to loop through all the word docs in this folder, opening them, updating the fields, saving and closing to avoid going through one by one and doing it manually.

Brand new to VBA here and not quite sure what I'm doing (or doing wrong). Here's the code I've pieced together so far based on responses I've seen related to this task. Any help is appreciated on how to improve this/tackle the problem. Happy to provide more info if it helps.

Receiving error "Object variable or With block variable not set" on line "Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(sFileName)"

Thanks!

**Update: Thank you everyone for the help, working code added below.**

```
Sub Sample()
Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object, rngStory As Object
Dim sFolder As String, strFilePattern As String
Dim strFileName As String, sFileName As String

'> Change this to the folder which has the files
sFolder = Dir(Range("A20").Value)

'> This is the extention you want to go in for
strFilePattern = "*.doc"

'> Establish Word application object
On Error Resume Next
Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

oWordApp.Visible = True

'> Loop through the folder to get the word files
strFileName = Dir$(sFolder & strFilePattern)
Do Until strFileName = ""
    sFileName = sFolder & strFileName

    '> Open the word doc
    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(sFileName)

    '> Update Fields
   
     oWordDoc.Fields.Update
        


    '> Close the file after saving
    oWordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=True

    '> Find next file
    strFileName = Dir$()
Loop

'> Quit and clean up
oWordApp.Quit

Set oWordDoc = Nothing
Set oWordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Updated Working Code:**

```
Sub UpdateSpecHeaders()
Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object
Dim sFolder As String, strFilePattern As String
Dim strFileName As String, sFileName As String

'> Folder containing files to update
sFolder = Range("A20").Value


    '> Identify file extension to search for
strFilePattern = "*.doc"


'> Establish a Word application object
On Error Resume Next
Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

oWordApp.Visible = True


'> Loop through the folder to get the word files
strFileName = Dir$(sFolder & strFilePattern)
Do Until strFileName = ""
    sFileName = sFolder & strFileName

    '> Open the word doc
    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(sFileName)
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False


    '> Update Fields
    oWordApp.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
     

    '> Save and close the file
    oWordDoc.Save
    oWordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
        
    '> Find next file
    strFileName = Dir$()
Loop

'> Quit and clean up
oWordApp.Quit

Set oWordDoc = Nothing
Set oWordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Your variable names are not consistent, `oWordDoc` / `WordDoc` and `oWordApp` / `WordApp`. Additional, because you start the macro from excel ActiveDocument is not clearly. Try there `oWordDoc.Fields.Update`

Comment: @Shrotter Thank you for the reply. I updated the variable names to be consistent along with the field update component. I'm now getting an error stating "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: can you please update the code in your question? On which line/object do you get the error?

Comment: Updated the post and code. The error is occurring at the code to open the word doc.

Comment: Please check the value of strFileName  and sFileName (MsgBox or watch window)

Comment: The following may assist you with the Word object model handling relative field paths. http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html

Comment: `sFolder = Dir(Range("A20").Value)` - `Dir(someString)` only returns the first matching file or folder name: it does not give you a full path.  Maybe you meant `sFolder = Range("A20").Value`, assuming A20 has a full path (with terminating backslash).

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help! I got it up and running this afternoon and it seems to be working great, going to poke around and see if I can speed it up a little bit. I've updated the post to include the working code.